# undefined reference to a function in a multi source file project

Tags: c++, c

I get the error
**undefined reference to 'chk(int)'**
from the Code::Blocks IDE and was able to simplify the problem down to the following

la_main.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "la_chk.h"
#include "la_1.h"

int x;
void prt_msg(char *string_buffer, int i)
{
  x = chk(i==0); //returns 0 if TRUE
  if(x==0) printf("%s", string_buffer);
}
```

la_main.h

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

INT i, p;

#endif // MAIN_H
```

la_1.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "la_chk.h"
#include "la_1.h"

int x;
strcpy(string_buffer, "Ok, match");
void prt_msg(char *string_buffer, int i)
{
  x = chk(i==0); //returns 0 if TRUE
  if(x==0) printf("%s", string_buffer);
}
```

la_1.h

```
#ifndef LA_1_H
#define LA_1_H

extern int x;
extern char buf[256];
void prt_msg(char *, int);

#endif
```

la_chk.c

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "la_chk.h"

INT chk(BOOL i)
/* ==============
** test, if FALSE -> return 1
**       if TRUE  -> return 0
*/
{
  if(i) {
    return(0);
  }else {
    return(1);
  }
}
```

la_chk.h

```
#ifndef LA_CHK_H
#define LA_CHK_H

//INT chk(BOOL);

#endif

INT chk(BOOL);
```

In this last h-file I tried both versions for 'INT chk(BOOL);', no difference in the result.
Why Code::Blocks dosn't see the function prototype in la_main and la_1 ??

Comment: Try declaring the chk function `extern "C"`

Comment: If you're just starting out, I don't recommend mixing C and C++ code, as this is only the first of many pitfalls you'll encounter in doing so.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo `strcpy(string_buffer, "Ok, match");` can't be used outside a function.

Comment: Why do you have 2 implementations of `ptr_msg`?

Comment: Thanks for your help - adding **extern** to the chk() prototype solve this problem (and i will modify la_chk.c to cpp to make things cleaner)  solved